# Visual Studio 2013 Publish window takes 30 seconds to load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

The Publish window takes 30 seconds to load in my ASP.NET MVC5 project. Previously, it loaded instantaneously.

If i remove the PublishProfiles folder, the window loads at once. Its only after i've saved an actual publish profile this occurs.

Some more information:

- Visual Studio 2013, fully updated.
- ASP.NET Web Application
- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- MVC 5

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: A new empty project does not have this issue. Therefor the problem must be project-related. I copied the publish pubxml into the new project and the window loaded quickly.

Comment: I dont know how to proceed...